# Sbt - maven parent equivalent

Tags: maven, sbt

Is there an equivalent of `maven` `parent` tag in `Sbt`:

```
  <parent>
      <groupId>com.sample.parent</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact_name</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
  </parent>
```

Appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sbt doesn't support maven parent tag equivalent as of 1.2.8. Recommends creating/using sbt plugins.